# Searching with Java using Google

Tags: java, search, hyperlink

I am trying to use Java to search for a String on Google. I heard about a Google API but I wasn't able to find anything useful. It should look something like this:

I have a text file. Every Line is a String which should be googled. If the first search result is from a spezific site (for example: stackoverflow.com/****), The full link will be written in a new textfile. Any ideas how to realize that?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search on Google with its [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview). There's a [Java Client Library for CustomSearch API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#CustomSearch_API) available to simplify the work. Warning : "Usage is free for all users, up to 100 queries per day."

Answer (score 0):

Goolge offers a RESTful service to do custom queries programmatically called the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview).

It is not free though: you can submit up to 100 queries per day.